# Delete parts of mesh in a shape key animation?

Tags: modeling, animation

I have a character with arms, I want to make those arms shrink back and disappear into his body in an animation.

I tried using a shape key to scale all the vertices down, but the problem is when I have all those vertices clustered together on the character in one spot it forms weird shadows.

Is there any way to delete part of the mesh in one shape key?

Comment: no. A shape key must retain all its vertices. You will have to come up with a strategy that handles all the arm vertices converging. I would guess grouping them with out overlapping, try the Select non Manifold geometry. Or create sleeves or a clever bit of lighting/camera work to hid the results. Good luck!

Comment: If your vertices are too close or overlap, try smooth them in edit mode: W -> O